# \newline not working with longtable?

Tags: line-breaking, longtable

This table comes from SAS output.  The \newline is not working correctly.  E.g. "Percent trimmed in tail" ought to be

Percent
Trimmed
In tail

but it is showing up as

Percent Trimmed In Tail

Here is a minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{url}
\lstloadlanguages{SAS} \lstset{language = SAS}

\begin{document}
 \begin{longtable}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}\hline
   \multicolumn{9}{|c|}{Trimmed Means}\\\hline
   Percent {\newline} Trimmed \newline in Tail &    Number \newline Trimmed \newline in Tail &    Trimmed \newline Mean &    Std Error \newline Trimmed \newline Mean &    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{95\%~Confidence~Limits} &    DF &    t for H0: \newline Mu0=0.00 &    Pr~>~|t|\\\hline
\endhead
   10.27 &    27 &    463.8867 &    25.08152 &    414.4401 &    513.3332 &    208 &    18.49516 &    <.0001\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need a cell spec with `p{<width>}` for `\newline` to work.

Comment: If you want to have an explicit line break, use `\thead` for example (requires `makecell`). Is this an auto-generated table?

Comment: Yes, the table was generated by SAS, but not quite correctly, apparently.

Comment: @Peter Flom: No, not really. The math LaTeX is weird ;-) And I've got no idea what SAS is at all.

Comment: `\newline` is working correctly: it is ignored in that context. as you have specified the cells to be `r` which are single-line entries.

Comment: I should correct myself, `\makecell` is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, `\makecell` worked.    SAS is a software suite that does statistics and a lot of other things.

Comment: @PeterFlom: Apparently its LaTeX code generator is ... well, not optimized ;-)?

Comment: :-).  Mostly, it works fine.  This is the first problem I have had with it.

Comment: @PeterFlom: I hope it can be trained to produce better output or you have to drop its LaTeX export feature

Answer (score 1):

Now you can write multiline cells without fixing the column widths with the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Caption},
  label = {tblr:test},
]{
  colspec={|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}, rowhead = 2, row{2}={m},
  cell{1}{1} = {c=9}{c}, cell{2}{5} = {c=2}{c},
}
\hline
 Trimmed Means \\
\hline
 {Percent \\ Trimmed \\ in Tail} & {Number \\ Trimmed \\ in Tail} & {Trimmed \\ Mean} &
 {Std Error \\ Trimmed \\ Mean}  & {$95\%$ \\ Confidence Limits} & & DF &
 {$t$ for $H_0$: \\ $\mu_0=0.00$} & $\mathrm{Pr}>|t|$ \\
\hline
 $10.27$ & $27$ & $463.8867$ & $25.08152$ & $414.4401$ & $513.3332$ & $208$ & $18.49516$ & $<.0001$ \\
\hline
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]