# New line in tabular does not create a new line

Tags: tables, line-breaking

There is a problem while I use newline in the tabular environment. Namely, from the following exemple in the column 3 the \newline adds a new line and it works as intended, however in the column 4 no new line is created for \newline command (please check the attached image below). Could you please tell why does it appear? By the way I am using array package.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}|l|}
        \hline
        \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} ID & text & text & text \\
        \hline
        \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} 1 & text & text &  text1 \newline text2\\
        \hline
        \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} 2 & text & text &  \\
        \hline
        \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} 3 & text & text &  \\
        \hline
        \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} 4 & text& text &  \\
        \hline
        \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} 5 & text  & text1 \newline text2 & text1 \newline text 2\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: You define the fourth column as `l` type, so no line break is allowed.

Comment: Need p-type. Similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254388/newline-not-working-with-longtable#comment608066_254388

Comment: you could also use another `tabular` in the affecting cell: `\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l @{}} text 1\\text 22 \end{tabular}` if you want to stick to the `l` column type.

Comment: @user202729, what does l and p mean? It seems that I have to add |>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}| as in the column 3, otherwise just |p| gives an error.

Comment: You can load the `makecell` package and use `\makecell[l]{text1 \\ text2}` for standard  column types.

Comment: @Celdor, I just want to have a proper table, no sticking to |l| required :)

Comment: I see. `p{<width>}` simply fixes its column width to `<width>`, in oppose to `l` which adjusts a column width to its content. `p{}` also changes a vertical alignment to top from the default middle. Other similar column types such as `m{}` and `b{}` do the same as `p{}` but change vertical alignments to middle and bottom, respectively.

Comment: Maybe read texdoc array. (source [tables - Definition/explantion of tabular column types - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99094/definition-explantion-of-tabular-column-types))

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in comments below question:

- Text in a cell can only be broken in so-called "paragraph" cells, i.e. in cells in columns of type `p{<width>}`, `m{<width>}` or `b{<width>}`, which are defines an array package or in the `X` type defined by the `tabularx` package.
  -In these cells text longer then cells width is broken automatically, however is possible force  to break it by `\newline` or `\par` or with inserting empty line between paragraphs in cells.
- Cells in columns of type `c`, `l` and `r` text cannot be broken. In those cells their width is adopted to width of contained text.

Some remarks about how to write your table:

- use of `\rule` for horizontal lines is wrong. For those lines are defined `\hline` and `cline`.
- beside them are exist plenty of other lines defined packages as `booktabs`, `hhline`, etc.
- new packages for writing tables -- `nicematrix` and `tabularray` enables to define all table lines in theirs preambles.

An example of table written by use of `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {c l Q[l, wd=50mm] Q[l, wd=3em]},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c}
             }
ID  & text  & text  &   text                \\
1   & text  & text  &   text1 text2 \\
2   & text  & text  &                       \\
3   & text  & text\newline text2   
                    &                       \\
4   & text  & text\par text2   
                    &                       \\
5   & text  & text1

              text2 & text1 \newline text 2 \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

For `tabularray` syntax please consult package documentation, where it is thoroughly and concise explained.